# Navigate to a screen of parent navigator from child navigator screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to React Native and I have been building a simple Food Recipe app. My main `Stack Navigator` contains two screens: `Bottom Tab Navigator` and `Recipe screen`. I am in `Home screen` in the `Tab Navigator` and when I press any recipe, I want to pass recipe props and navigate to `Recipe screen` in the main `Stack Navigator`. Unfortunately, I haven't found any solution to this.
Could you please help me solve this?

This is the main file `App.js`

```
const Navigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    Add: Add,
    Profile: Profile
  }
);

const Stack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Navigator: Navigator,
    Recipe: Recipe
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    navigationOptions: {
        headerVisible: false,
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(Stack)
```

This is my `Home Screen` class

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Recipes</Text>
                </View>

                <ScrollView style={styles.categoryContainer}>
                    <Category name={"All Foods"} recipes={recipes} />
                    <Category name={"Meat"} recipes={[ recipes[1], recipes[3] ]} />
                    <Category name={"Vegetarian"} recipes={[ recipes[0], recipes[2] ]} />
                    <Category name={"Desserts"} recipes={[ recipes[4] ]} />
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the `Category` class

```
export default class Category extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.categoryHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.categoryHeaderTitle}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                </View>

                <ScrollView >
                    <View style={styles.categoryContent}>
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.props.recipes}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => <Block name={item.name} image={item.image} time={item.time} portions={item.portions} />}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                            horizontal={true}
                        /> 
                    </View>  
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the actual recipe block where I want to navigate all the way back to the `Recipe screen` and pass recipe props using `onPress={}` function

```
export default class Block extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={null} >
                <Image style={styles.image} source={this.props.image} />

                <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.info}>{this.props.time} min | portions: {this.props.portions}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you for all your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `StackNavigator` to display a header on top of a `BottomTabNavigator` i would suggest to use a `StackNavigator` for every child of the `bottomTabBar`. Doing like that you can have more screens in a single `tabBarItem`, and you won't have the bottomTabBar disappearing for the other screens.

If you don't mind of this, you can access your `stackNavigator` from his child using `dangerouslyGetParent` and then navigate with the props you need.

```
navigateToRecipe = (recipe) => {
   this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().navigate("Recipe", { recipe : myRecipe}) //pass an object with the data you need
}
```

Then you can access your recipe props either using getParam `this.props.navigation.getParam("recipe")` or directly using `this.props.navigation.state.params`

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. However, a new problem has risen and that is that I am not passing ```this.props.navigation``` properly across the classes all the way to the ```Block.js``` class and therefore ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating –this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent)``` error was outputed. How to pass these the right way for it to work?

Comment: You can either pass it from parent down to block doing `navigation = { this.props.navigation }` or use the `withNavigation` HOC provided by react-navigation : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html

Comment: After passing it using ```navigation = { this.props.navigation }``` all the way to the ```Block``` class, React Native still can't recognize the prop. However, the second option works just fine. Thank you very much for your help!